# Ubuntu 22 interface (Gnome) becomes choppy after a while

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, 22.04, performance

My new install of Ubuntu 22.04 on Asus Zenbook i7-1165G7 system becomes choppy after some time. Usually after I left it on lock screen or it came back from suspend.

It's not slow, it seems to suffer from micro-locks where it hangs for a split second and then continues. Also, when typing in this state some keys will be typed in multiple times despite me pressing them once.

**What can I do to debug this issue?**

Maybe it's related to some power saving measure? The Gnome power profile (performance/balanced/power saving) doesn't seem to matter. I have tlp on. Or perhaps something with the Intel platform itself, like they removed S3?

EDIT: There are some worrying signs in logs but nothing that would point me to the cause

```
Aug 01 10:15:08 ubuntu22machine gnome-shell[4106]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
```

repeated for multiple lines, and then again

```
Aug 01 10:28:24 ubuntu22machine gnome-shell[4106]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
Aug 01 10:28:24 ubuntu22machine gnome-shell[3315]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (51117390) is greater than comparison timestamp (51117001).  This most likely represents a b>
Aug 01 10:28:24 ubuntu22machine gnome-shell[3315]: Window manager warning: 0xc0003d appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 51117390.  Working around...
Aug 01 10:28:29 ubuntu22machine gnome-shell[4106]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
```

or maybe wayland *is* the cause, not some underlying resource issue. I will try running on X11.

EDIT2: [Launchpad tracks a similar bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1975935) where the suspect is a stray gnome extension. I will look into it after testing Xorg.

Comment: Do your logs have any clues?

Comment: @user535733 Which logs would you like to see?

Comment: Review your logs, and show us the clues you find. Start with your /var/log/syslog and your journalctl. Entries are timestamped, so be sure to review times around when the problem occurs, including the seconds before the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the suggestion from Launchpad was correct and one of the extensions was in fact responsible for the choppiness.

The current suspects are:

- Hibernate Status Button,
- OpenWeather,
- Toggle Night Light,
- WireGuard Indicator

or some combination of them with other extensions. It's not clear. I went on quite an extension bender.

It's possible that the default

- Desktop Icons NG (DING)

also contributed to the issue.

I stopped experimenting after narrowing it this far down since none of these are important enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and for me indicator-multiload was still in Startup Applications despite me thinking I'd removed it and it not appearing in the taskbar. Apparently it was still turning on and running behind the scenes causing massive issues.

Comment: I only have one of my scripts and ssh agent in startup applications. But a good idea to check.